# SELECT Statement with correlated/nested Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have two tables in my database, `Department` & `DepartmentErrors`. 
The `DepartmentErrors` table contains a column called '`Error`

I would like to run a select statement on the `Department` table, matching any related occurrences of that department within `DepartmentError`, where the `Error` value matches a number. I would then like to append a column onto that result set, for each department, containing how many rows matching that department ID & Error value have appeared within the department error table. This is my code so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Department.DeptID,
    Name,
    Size,
    Location,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM DepartmentErrors
        INNER JOIN Departments ON DepartmentErrors.DeptID = Departments.DeptID
        WHERE Error = 2
    ) AS ErrorCount
FROM Departments
INNER JOIN DepartmentErrors ON Departments.DeptID = DepartmentErrors.DeptID
WHERE DepartmentErrors.Error = 2
```

Comment: Tag your question properly. `mysql` and `sql-server` are two different products.

Comment: @John Bergqvist: You were not supposed to remove *both* `mysql` and `sql-server` tags, but only remove the incorrect one and keep the correct one. With the `sql` tag alone, we know this is about the SQL language, but don't know the DBMS - which could be helpful to know as SQL dialects differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT d.DeptID,
       d.Name,
       d.Size,
       d.Location,
       e.ErrorCount
FROM Departments d
JOIN (
    SELECT DeptID, ErrorCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM DepartmentErrors
    WHERE Error = 2
    GROUP BY DeptID
) e ON d.DeptID = e.DeptID
```